# enable netbeans 7.1 SQL code completion

Tags: php, sql, netbeans, code-completion

How do I enable SQL code completion in netbeans 7.1? I used to be able to do it in 7.0.

Comment: Have you set up a database connection?

Comment: BTW, the close vote wasn't me, I think this is on-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah i have a connection setup, but it doesn't offer the code completion pop up when I start typing an SQL command. I'm wondering if they removed SQL support like how they removed python and ruby -.-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL code completion works fine for me, with a fresh install of Netbeans 7.1 with the PHP plugin on Ubuntu 11.10 against MySql 5.1.

Once I'd set up a connection I was able to use code completion both in .sql files and in variables in PHP code (start a string with `"SELECT` and then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>).

I suggest starting Netbeans with a [clean userdir](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir) to see if this resolves your problem.

Comment: solved it by just reinstalling the whole thing and deleting the user settings. Thanks!